# resize image when UISheetPresentationController is fully opened

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've implemented an `UISheetPresentationController` in my project, what I want to do is simple, when the `ViewController` is fully opened (`sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()])` large one ) with `UISheetPresentationController` I want the image inside `ViewController` to get also larger

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
        if let sheet = backDropActionSheet.sheetPresentationController {
            sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
            sheet.preferredCornerRadius = 30
            sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = true
            sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
        }
        self.present(backDropActionSheet,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
    ///SheetPresentationController code below
    @IBOutlet weak var countryImage: UIImageView!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontrollerdelegate) protocol to react to the sheet detent size changing.

```
sheet.delegate = self
```

And then:

```
extension MyViewController: UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
    
    func sheetPresentationControllerDidChangeSelectedDetentIdentifier(_ sheetPresentationController: UISheetPresentationController) {
        if sheetPresentationController.selectedDetentIdentifier == .large {
            //increase image size for example
        }
    }
    
}
```